# How can we reverse the functionality to copy billing Address to shipping Address in Account object?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

Actually there was an existed functionality to copy billing Address to shipping Address in Account object. But i want to create a button so that shipping address have to copy into billing address.

Comment: Voting down because you show no sign of having tried things yourself, and the same holds for your comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can create page and controller and call them from the button

```
public with sharing class CopyBilling {
   string accId;
   public CopyBilling (){
        accId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accId');
    }

    public PageReference copy(){
          Account acc = ...
          return  new PageReference('/'+acc.Id)
    }

}

<apex:page controller="CopyBilling" action="{!copy}"></apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you provide full code. As i want search code but my criteria is different as i have custom Address fields which have to copy to billing address fields through button functionality. Please provide as it is urgent.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a custom check box field and workflow field update. Slightly more rudimentary, but it works.

Create a custom checkbox 'copy shipping to billing' on the account object.

Create immediate workflow actions of 'field update' for each field you want copied over. Select 'Use a formula to set the new value' and insert the corresponding shipping address field for each field update.

On save, the record with replace the billing fields with the shipping fields.